# Specify supertype of JvmTypeReference in Xtext grammar

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, xtext

Is it possible to specify a required type (e.g. interface) for a JvmTypeReference in an Xtext grammar?

**Example**

```
Instantiation:
    ('new' type=JvmTypeReference (params=Params)?)
;
```

Where `type=JvmTypeReference` must be an `instanceof` some specified class.

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible in the grammar, but you can achieve the desired behavior by means of a customized scope provider or a proposal provider, see this blog post: https://kthoms.wordpress.com/2012/03/14/how-to-limit-proposed-java-types-to-implementors-of-an-interface/

Comment: Note the comment at the bottom of the blog post: implementing the proposal provider limits just the content assist. You should then also add a validation.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a reference to a JvmConstructor!

```
Instantiation:
    'new' type=[JvmConstructor|QualifiedName] params=Params?;
```

You should use an XimportSection in your grammar then you can write a scope provider where you can scope directly to any constructor.